# Windows 7 data restore

Tags: windows-7

When booting up my laptop, it come up with this error message:

```
Windows Error Recovery:
Windows failed to start up. A recent hardware or software change might be the cause.
```

If windows files have been damaged or configured incorrectly.
it will give my two options:
Launch Startup Repair
Or
Start windows normally
either option takes me to this next screen:
end user license agreement
and then this one takes me to:
create system recovery media, after about 5 minutes, this take me to:
`The file or directory D: windows\winsxs\manifests is corrupt and unreadable please run the chkdsk utility.` (which I cannot run)
This takes me to create systems recovery (which does nothing).

My main question is if I use my Windows 7 restore disk will I lose all of my data?

Comment: If you are worried about losing your data you should create an image of the current contents of the hdd.  This way even if you do suffer data loss you have a backup of the current state of your hdd allowing you to view the contents of the image and restoring the files manually.

Comment: I cannot even get to the desktop to save. Not very computer savvy.

Answer (score 0):

Hello there is always a possibility that You can lose Your data.

I suggest to download Hiren's BootCD (please find it in Google), burn it onto CD, and boot from it  to get access to Your data
it is in (C:\Users\ ...Your User name)
Then copy it to an external HDD. 
Next, You can boot from Your Windows7 DVD, choose Startup Repair, and if this doesn't work, try to install over a corrupted Windows installation (same disk, same directory - just don't format the drive). In a second scenario You will need to re-install all programs afterward, because they will stop working, but there is chance data will be intact.

 Good luck

Comment: Instead Hiren Boot, You can download and use Ubuntu Linux - it will be even easier